# Issues with interrupts coming from RTC DS3231 and power supply interference

Tags: interrupt

Several months ago I developed a device able to detect water flood in a closed space and do some operations in case (closing valves, issuing an acoustic and Bluetooth alarm etc.).

After 8 hours it tries to reopen the valves and restart the normal cycle. Arduino UNO is always in sleeping mode (this device remains active 7/24). It wakes up every minute (@ sec.00) to detect presence of water, checks for 4 cycles (4 minutes) the presence of water -if the sensors are on- and then, after have issued the alarms and closed the valves, it wakes up after 8 hours, in order to reopen the valves and come back in its normal check-mode.

It worked and works flawlessly, when left working on my table. I tried it for almost a month.  The problem raised when I installed it in place, because there is a water pump (an autoclave, of some 1,5Hp, 1 phase), connected on the same power supply line, that -of course- starts whenever somebody opens a water valve at home.

Whenever it starts, Arduino wakes up immediately and the 1 minute (or 8 hours waiting cycle) stops.

- I tried to use several caps on the 12V power supply line (some 3000uF, 50Vl in total) and a EMI filter between the power supply line and my device, but nothing changed.
- I made some mods on the software, checking if the wakeup hour and minute is compatible with the correctly wakeup time calculated and setted on Arduino, and storing an alarm flag with wakeup hour and minute in EEPROM, in order to manage the same check if Arduino undergoes a hardware reset or is turned off/on.

I suspect that the problem raises for the fact that the RTC interrupt is activated when the IRQ pin is lowered from the HIGH state.
There is a way to set the DS3231 to remain in LOW state always, and issue a HIGH level just for the interrupts?

Does anybody have any electrical suggestion? I use this [12V chinese switching UPS/power supply](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CADANIA-SC-120W-12V10A-Switching-Monitor-Battery/dp/B07TDJ1BLF/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) connected to a 12V-7Ah lead battery that assures no interruptions.

Comment: I don't know how to ask you clarifying questions about this without them also implicitly containing an answer: best attempt show the wiring and find out whether or not you're tripping the UNO's brownout detector.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I'm puzzled a little bit. 
my power supply gives some 10A (@13,4V), and it's connected to a big 12V-7Amps (4,5lbs) brand new lead battery (*) to Arduino (on VIN pin+ground) + a 7805.

The 7805 feeds a couple of water sensors (less than 5mA each), the DS3231RTC, 3 LEDs plus the relais board (2 relais, some 55mA each when excited), of course all the grounds connected togheter.

(*)  https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B071JMHMN6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I did not draw the wiring diagram yet, but I will make it ASAP

Comment: It would probably help to see it diagrammed. In your `setup()` can you do something like blink an led with an easily recognizable pattern such that if your Arduino UNO resets, you will be able to tell very clearly?

Comment: yes. I normally do not write diagrams for very simple circuits, but its just a my fault, of course.
In the front of my device there are 3 main leds, I blink them all for 1/2 second in the setup function.
They don't light up during these strange "resets".
I believe that something different happens, like just a unexpected, wakeup that happens just when a transient noise happens in line power.
I prepared a new firmw. version (that I will try tomorrow) in which I always check datetime after the wakeup, reading it from the EEPROM, in which I write in case of flood, just before to go to sleep.

Comment: Today I've done other tests:
1) Arduino does not emit serial messags after those strange resets - it' clearly visible that continues to work by the blinking leds - to obtain messages it's needed to reset Arduino (close/reopen serial window in IDE or push reset);
2) changing power line does not change anything - I connected it to another power line, completely isolated from the original one and the problem persists;
3) leaving it powered just by the big battery does not change anything (!) when the pump starts Arduino wakes up!
 
...an EMI? I connected all the grounds to earth

Comment: Without compilable code and a diagram there's not much for me to ask, say, or do.

Comment: My guess would be EMI. Can you twist and shield the power lines from the big battery to the Arduino? Do you have a oscilloscope? You could try to see if there is a spike in the 5V power to the Arduino when the pump starts running.